# MS SQL Convert rows to columns with Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

in MS SQL
I have following table

[image: source table]

I would like to convert it to :

[image: Destination table]

I had a look at pivot table function, but could not get it work correctly.
Any advice?

Comment: *"I had a look at pivot table function, but could not get it work correctly"* And what was that attempt? You forgot to include it. Why didn't the attempt work? Also, don't post images of data. Provide sample data as text; preferably as DDL and DML statements but at least as well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud try this:

```
With data (STOCKCODE, QTY, AGE) as (
select 'AIRFIL01', 3,1 union all
select 'AIRFIL01', 8,2  union all
select 'AIRFIL05', 4,1  union all
select 'AIRFIL05', 14,2  union all
select 'AIRPRE01', 4,1  union all
select 'AIRPRE01', 24,2  union all
select 'AIRSUS01', 1,2  union all
select 'ALARM01', 1,1  union all
select 'ALARM01', 6,2  union all
select 'ALARM01', 7,10  union all
select 'ALARM05', 2,1  union all
select 'ANTROL01', 5,2 
)
SELECT * from (
Select STOCKCODE, QTY, CONCAT('Age_' , AGE) comment  from data
)t
PIVOT
(
SUM(QTY)
FOR comment IN ( [Age_1],[Age_2],[Age_3],[Age_4],[Age_5],[Age_6],[Age_7],[Age_8],[Age_9],[Age_10])
) p
```

[image]